# Palindrome that ignores spaces and special characters and converts all uppercase letters in the string to lowercase

Tags: c

I'm going to make a palindrome which should ignore spaces and special characters and should convert all uppercase letters in the string to lowercase. I have done everything, but when I run my program, neither of these two functions work. Convert uppercase to lowercase and ignore all non-uppercase letters. Could any of you help me to solve what is the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 1000
#include <ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

// function that checks if it is a palindrome
int isPalindrome(char inputString[]) {

    int l = 0;
    int r = strlen(inputString) - 1;


    while (r > l)
    {
        // will check all letters are equal to each other
        if (inputString[l++] != inputString[r--]) {
            return 0;
        }// return 0 if not palindrome
    }
    // palindrome

    return 1;

}

// function that ignores all non - letters
int no_special_characters(char inputString[])
{
    char temp[SIZE];
    int temp_index = 0;
    int abc = 0;
    int r = strlen(inputString);
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        char abc = inputString[i];
        if (isalpha(abc) != 0)
        {
            temp[temp_index++] = abc;
        }
    }
    temp[temp_index] = '\0';

    return isPalindrome(temp);
}

// function that converts uppercase letters to lowercase

void to_lower(char inputstring[]) {

    int length = strlen(inputstring);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (isupper(inputstring[i]))
            inputstring[i] = tolower(inputstring[i]);
        else if (islower(inputstring[i]))
            inputstring[i] = toupper(inputstring[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}




int main(void) {


    int try_again = 1;
    int end_run = 0;

    while (try_again == 1) {
        int try_again;

        char inputString[SIZE] = "";

        printf("Enter a string to check if it is a palindrome!\n");
        //Scans the input string.
        scanf_s("%s", &inputString, SIZE);

        //Sends the string to the isPalindrome function. //If the return value is 1(true), the if statement is executed, otherwise the else statement.
        if (isPalindrome(inputString)) {
            printf("That is a palindrome!\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("This is not a palindrome!\n");
        }

        printf("Do you want to try again: 1 for yes 0 for No?");
        scanf_s("%d", &try_again);

        //Changes the value of running depending on whether you want to continue or not.
        if (try_again != 1) {
            end_run = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have several functions, you have to test them one by one.

Comment: Your `to_lower` function is converting upper case letters to lower case, and vice versa. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes: Ian Abbott

Comment: The palindrome function works for strings with matching case. *"neither of these two functions work"*. Your two other functions are **not called**. There is a syntax error in `to_lower()` - void function returning a value.

Comment: Is there any whitespace in the input, e.g. `dog god`? `scanf`'s `%s` will only read the first word, `dog`.

Comment: In the `scan_f` call, `&inputString` should be `inputString`. `inputString` gets converted to a pointer to its initial element.

Comment: That the problem i have, i dont know if  im doing the correct way to call the function Weather Vane, should i put  to_lower() and  int no_special_characters. Like int main(void) {  to_lower();
   
    }

    return 0;
}

Comment: You would have to build a new string by examining each character, and adjusting its case, or ignoring. Or use the same array if you like. Remember to write a new string terminator if you are going to pass it to `strlen`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many `try_again` variables do you think you need? And how do you expect `to_lower` to return *anything* when it is defined as return type `void` ?

Comment: You are correct WhozCraig. By the way,can i use char to_lower(char inputstring[]) or should i choose int.

Answer (score 0):

### 1 - Don't use scanf

You shouldn't use `scanf` to read input from the console, especially in a loop. I'm not an expert in `scanf_s` in particular, but that whole family of functions can cause weird bugs if you don't know how they work. I recommend you read [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112034702/http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html), it explains it better that I can.

### 2 - Your loop doesn't work

You are defining `try_again` in function scope and then redefining it in block scope: they are two different variables.
Your code is essentially this:

```
int main(void) {
    int try_again = 1;
    while (try_again == 1) {
        int try_again;
        scanf_s("%d", &try_again);
    }
}
```

Which will run forever, since the while loop is checking the first variable, while you are assigning to the second one. It should look more like this:

```
int main(void) {
    int try_again = 1;
    while (try_again == 1) {
        // int try_again;
        // ^^ Don't refefine - use the one already defined
        try_again = some_function_to_read_input();
    }
}
```

### 3 - `to_lower` doesn't actually convert to lowercase

It converts uppercase to lowercase and lowercase to uppercase. This means "Aa" becomes "aA", which is not a palindrome even though it should be by your definition.

The function doesn't need to return anything, since it changes the string in place. You can simply call it like this:

```
int isPalindrome(char inputString[]) {
    to_lower(inputString);
    // Rest of code
}
```

### 4 - You aren't calling `no_special_characters`

You simply aren't calling it. Either you do it in your `main`, something like:

```
// main
if (no_special_characters(inputString)) {
    // Rest of code
}
```

Or you change it to return the modified string and call it from inside `isPalindrome`:

```
void no_special_characters(char inputString[]) {
  // Remove all special characters, in place
}

int isPalindrome(char inputString[]) {
    no_special_characters(inputString);
    to_lower(inputString);
    // Rest of code
}
```